# difference of reading files

Tags: c#

```
string value1 = File.ReadAllText("C:\\file.txt");
string value2 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.txt");
```

In the above statements when is the difference of using **@"C:\file.txt"**  and **C:\file.txt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string value1 = "C:\file.txt";
string value2 = @"C:\file.txt";
```

the string for value1 will contain a formfeed character where the \f is, while the second one will keep the backslash and the f. (This becomes very clear if you try to output them in a console application with Console.Write...)

The correct way for the value1 version would be `"C:\\file.txt"`

(The value2 version uses whats called, as Dmitry said, a verbatim string)

Answer (score 5):

Compiler would read **@"C:\file.txt"** as is. Removing verbatim (@) will make it treat **'\f'** as a single escape character ([Form feed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)). In other words:

```
@"C:\file.txt" == "C:\\file.txt"
@"C:\file.txt" != "C:\file.txt" // treated as C: + FormFeed + ile.txt
```

> Verbatim string literals start with @ and are also enclosed in double
>   quotation marks. For example:
>
> ```
> @"good morning"  // a string literal
> ```
>
> The advantage of verbatim strings is that escape sequences are not
>   processed, which makes it easy to write, for example, a fully
>   qualified file name:
>
> ```
> @"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt"  // rather than "c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt"
> ```

[String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> A regular string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed
>   in double quotes, as in "hello", and may include both simple escape
>   sequences (such as \t for the tab character) and hexadecimal and
>   Unicode escape sequences.
>
> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing
>   double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim
>   string literal, the characters between the delimiters **are interpreted
>   verbatim**, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In
>   particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim
>   string literal may span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `\` in a string, you normally have to use `\\` because the `\` is an escape character.  In reality, the first string you show (`File.ReadAllText("C:\file.txt");`) should throw a compile error.

The `@` will allow you to build your string without using `\\` every time you need a `\`.